# Grouping same values python

Tags: python

I have this list that contains the following:

```
portugal;lisbon 1234
england;london 3214
france;paris 1928
germany;berlin 1923
portugal;lisbon 1902
spain;madrid 1764
spai;barcelona 1856
portugal;porto 5463
italy;rome 4344
netherlands;amesterdam 4444
portugal;lisbon 2999
italy;napoles 1290
russia;moscow 1999
```

How can i group the lines with the same name?

portugal;lisbon shows up 3 times with diff values, how can i parse a file containing this data and group lines that have matching names in to a variable?

Comment: Whats the type of the data? Is it a string, a csv file or something else?

Comment: what is the output you are looking?

Comment: You can simply sort the file and then group adjacent lines with the same prefix with a very simple script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could parse it into a dictionary:

```py
raw = # ... the data here
data = {}
for line in raw.split('\n'):
    place, number = line.split()    # default is ' '
    if place in data:
        data[place].append(number)
    else:
        data[place] = [number]
```

This would produce a dictionary called `data` mapping place name to a list of numbers. You could make this even more simple with a `defaultdict`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict


raw = # ... the data here
data = defaultdict(list)
for line in raw.split('\n'):
    place, number = line.split()    # default is ' '
    data[place].append(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

The defaultdict should be able to help .
It will group the values into the same Key
https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict

ip = """portugal;lisbon 1234
england;london 3214
france;paris 1928
germany;berlin 1923
portugal;lisbon 1902
spain;madrid 1764
spai;barcelona 1856
portugal;porto 5463
italy;rome 4344
netherlands;amesterdam 4444
portugal;lisbon 2999
italy;napoles 1290
russia;moscow 1999"""

li = defaultdict(list)

for i in ip.split("\n"):
    param = i.split()
    li[param[0]].append(param[1])

print(li)
```

op:

```
{'portugal;lisbon': ['1234', '1902', '2999'], 'england;london': ['3214'], 'france;paris': ['1928'], 'germany;berlin': ['1923'], 'spain;madrid': ['1764'], 'spai;barcelona': ['1856'], 'portugal;porto': ['5463'], 'italy;rome': ['4344'], 'netherlands;amesterdam': ['4444'], 'italy;napoles': ['1290'], 'russia;moscow': ['1999']}
```

Answer (score 0):

- It's unclear where the data is coming from
- If the data is coming from a csv file, use [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv)
- The benefit of using pandas is, the data is now easily manipulated and can be analyzed.

  - Below, the data will be grouped by `'Country'` and `'City'` into a `list`, and `sum` groups of values.

    - Using `sum` is just an example of other options available in pandas.
- Specific rows and columns can be accessed with [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or [`pandas.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html#pandas.DataFrame.iloc)

```py
import pandas as pd

# read the file
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='\\s+', header=None)

# display(df.head())
                 0     1
0  portugal;lisbon  1234
1   england;london  3214
2     france;paris  1928
3   germany;berlin  1923
4  portugal;lisbon  1902

# separate the countries and cities
df[['Country', 'City']] = df[0].str.split(';', expand=True)

# drop column 0
df.drop(columns=[0], inplace=True)

# display(df.head())
      1   Country    City
0  1234  portugal  lisbon
1  3214   england  london
2  1928    france   paris
3  1923   germany  berlin
4  1902  portugal  lisbon

# use groupby on the Country and City column and aggregate a list
dfg = df.groupby(['Country', 'City'])[1].agg([list, sum]).reset_index()

# display(dfg)

        Country        City                list   sum
0       england      london              [3214]  3214
1        france       paris              [1928]  1928
2       germany      berlin              [1923]  1923
3         italy     napoles              [1290]  1290
4         italy        rome              [4344]  4344
5   netherlands  amesterdam              [4444]  4444
6      portugal      lisbon  [1234, 1902, 2999]  6135
7      portugal       porto              [5463]  5463
8        russia      moscow              [1999]  1999
9          spai   barcelona              [1856]  1856
10        spain      madrid              [1764]  1764
```